# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Local server duplicating resources

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

Every time i try to create a new Worklight server all of my resources get duplicated... and I believe its causing errors when i deploy.

[image]

What I have tried to fix this issue so far:

1. Deleted server, and created a new one. Same result
2. Deleted my workspace and started from scratch. Same result
3. Completed removed eclipse from my workstation. Same result

Is there any other explaination for this behavior? I am using a fresh Eclipse Luna SR2 install, with a fresh install of the MFP 7.1 plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known APAR: PI50480 ALL MOBILEFIRST SERVER .WAR FILES IN MOBILEFIRST STUDIO APPEAR TWICE

The development team is working on fixing it. That said, this duplication has no effect on your project. You can ignore it.

Comment: Ok Great, thought I was going crazy for a minute... Thank you.