# MFP development server displays 2 of everything

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Hi I am trying to set up MFP 7.1 development server on my local. I installed eclipse and MF studio. Everything went fine. i could even create a HelloWorld MFPF project. But i noticed 2 of everything under Mobile First Developement Server [ worklight] [Started, Synchronized] in the 'Server" tab . I see 2 AnalysticsServices, 2 AnalyticalUI, 2 WorklightConsole and 2 WorklightServices. Anything wrong with my setup? How can fix it?[screenshot of the workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTVkr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please search first: [IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Local server duplicating resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271774/ibm-mobilefirst-7-1-local-server-duplicating-resources)

This is a known APAR: PI50480 ALL MOBILEFIRST SERVER .WAR FILES IN MOBILEFIRST STUDIO APPEAR TWICE

The development team is working on fixing it. That said, this duplication has no effect on your project. You can ignore it.